# Trying to create an impossible graph?

Tags: r, data-visualization, categorical-data, ggplot2

I want to create a graph, but I'm not sure if it even exists because I couldn't find any example that makes use of it.

To illustrate the problem, I'll make some data up. Let's say I want to represent the percentage of kids regarding the color of the hair (`Blonde`, `Brown`, `Black`, `Albino`, and `Redhair`) in four states (`Vermont`, `Alaska`, `Florida`, and `California`).

I'd have something like this:

```
State <- c("Vermont", "Alaska", "Florida", "California")
Blond <- c(11, 19, 10, 2)
Brown <- c(14, 11, 50, 38)
Albino <- c(22, 45, 0, 22)
Black <- c(23, 5, 1, 0)
Redhair <- c(25, 20, 39, 38)

state_hair <- data.frame (State, Blond, Brown, Albino, Black, Redhair)
```

The graph I want would be the x axis with the states, the y axis divided in five panels (one for each color), and the percentage represented as a rectangle where the width is fixed, but the height is the percentage of kids with that hair color in that state.

I have drawn my idea of the graph (loosely based in the previous data).

[image: Ideal graph]

Before and after transforming the data frame from wide to long (`reshape2`, `melt`), I've tried with `lattice` and `ggplot2`, both with `boxplot` and violin (`panel.violin` and `geom_violin`, respectively), but because there is just one value, it does not make much sense.

Would it be possible or there is any flaw I can't see.

Comment: This looks a lot like a mosaic plot (package `vcd`, function `mosaicplot` or `strucplot`), if that's helpful.

Comment: Does not `mosaicplot` look like stacked bars with optional separation between them? Nice one, but not the one I was looking for. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution in ggplot2. Could definitely use some cleaning up. Also, I'm not sure why I had to add the limits in the scale. Without them, extra categories were being added on the x and y axes.

Basically I converted the data frame to long format and changed the factors to numbers. I used those numbers to set the xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax of rectangles.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
sh <- state_hair %>% gather(haircolor, percent, -State) %>% 
  mutate(hc = as.numeric(haircolor), st=as.numeric(State)) 

ggplot(sh, aes(xmin=st-.25, xmax=st+.25, ymax=hc+(percent/100), ymin=hc-(percent/100) )) + 
  geom_rect() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1"="Alaska","2"="California","3"="Florida","4"="Vermont"), 
    limits=c("1","2","3","4")) + 
  scale_y_discrete(labels=c("1" = "Blond", "2" = "Brown", "3" = "Albino", "4"="Black", "5" = "Redhead"),
    limits=c("1","2","3","4","5"))
```

Answer (score 5):

I can't offer any advice on `ggplot`, but to the terminology question: If all of the values in each state sum to 1, this would be called a [normalized stacked bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886394%20normalized%20stacked%20bar%20chart).

Comment: Yes, it was my first thought and I created it, but I'm pushing my desires to build a "prettier" graph.

By the way, fix your link so it points to http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886394

Thanks!

Comment: Prettier in the sense that you'd like the elements separated as shown?

Comment: Yes, in that sense. Of course, it is subjective, but I want it to be correct first of all.